# how to create a dynamic container in flutter according to image

Tags: flutter, containers

I am trying to develop an app which has a container which contains a network image now I want that size of the container to adjust according to the size or image like if the image is in portrait the container height should set accordingly and if the image is in landscape it can adjust accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap a `Container` around your `Image` widget.

I put you an exemple on this codepen:
https://codepen.io/blkkkbvsik/pen/MWKWwwN

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust the size of the container with an image. I think it is easier to expand your image to the size of the container, so you only need to control the `Container`'s size.

you can use the `Expanded` class.
Find the docs [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html).